# UPDATE ... SET expression must be a subquery

Tags: sql, jdbc, oracle10g

Can any one help me in this program. I'm stuck here.

```
public class UpdateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    String sql="update register set (fname,lname,contact,address,state,password,dob,question,answer)=(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)where loginid=?";

String sql1="update login set (password)=(?)where loginid=?";
```

I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01767: UPDATE ... SET expression must be a subquery" **

Comment: Although this is valid standard SQL, Oracle does not allow this. You have to use individual assignments per column as shown in Rahul's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cause your `UPDATE` statement looks like a `INSERT` statement. All the `SET` columns should be separated with `,`. It should be

```
update register set fname = ?,
lname = ?
......
where loginid=?
```